# println/print and spacing (beginning java)

Tags: java, arrays

My programming assignment was to print an array with 10 random integers and then have 4 lines with different outputs (every even element, reverse order, etc.)

The code itself works fine (as far as I can tell) but one problem I'm having is that I had to put a System.out.println(""); before every line in order for the lines to look correct.

Initially, when I had it System.out.println("[LINE 1]....") *for loop * System.out.print("arr[i] + ", ") *close for loop * it printed each integer on a separate line instead of all on one line. Am I missing something here?? Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random random = new Random();
        int arr[]=new int[10];
        System.out.print("The array of random numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(50);
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("[LINE 1] Elements at an even index: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i%2==0){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" (at index "+i + "), ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("[LINE 2] Every even element:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i]%2==0){
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("[LINE 3] Elements in reverse order: ");
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("[LINE 4] First Element is: "+arr[0]+" and Last ELement is: "+arr[arr.length-1]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The responses were helpful and I was able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this exemple:

```
        System.out.print("\n[LINE 2] Every even element:");
```

You have write **\n** because it is a simple way to introduce a newline although the right way isn't with **system.out.print**, the right way to this format is **system.out.format** like to c lenguage, but also used

Answer (score 1):

All overloads of the [`println` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) append a newline following whatever you want to print; all overloads of the `print` method don't.

If all you want is a newline, then you don't even have to supply an argument -- call the [no-argument `println` overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29).

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the code System.out.println("").

use "\n"

You can change System.out.print("[LINE 1] Elements at an even index: ") to System.out.print("\n[LINE 1] Elements at an even index: ").